# Reference for Whitney's approximation theorem for manifolds with boundary

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I am aware of Whitney's approximation theorem for manifolds without boundary but I was wondering if there is reference which states the above theorem for manifolds with boundary. Thank you.

Comment: I was asleep when you [asked me](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505975/applications-of-whitneys-approximation-theorem/1506013?noredirect=1#comment3070588_1506013), but now it's been answered.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks a lot So should I delete this question or should I let it stay as it is?

Comment: It's up to you. Perhaps you could find the precise reference to the appropriate theorem in Hirsch's book and post it as an answer, in case some other weary traveler finds it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One proof is given in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.), Theorem 9.27.

Comment: I have access to the first edition but not to the second edition. So could you please give some other link