# Arc connectedness

Tags: differential-geometry, connectedness

I was studying the relationship between connected space and arc connected space.
I know that they are equivalent on open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to know if i could always find an arc, linking two points of an open set, that is a regular curve.

Thank you

Comment: Try to look suggestions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243295/smooth-curves-on-a-path-connected-smooth-manifold/2713251#2713251). Maybe that will help.

Comment: @SiKucing Thank you, you've been very helpful.