# Can we make these curves regular?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, connectedness, path-connected

I have read these questions about smooth arc connected and arc connected manifolds:

[Smooth curves on a path connected smooth manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243295/smooth-curves-on-a-path-connected-smooth-manifold/2713251#2713251)

[Connectivity, Path Connectivity and Differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45976/connectivity-path-connectivity-and-differentiability)

But I'm working with a specific problem and having those arcs regular would be pretty nice. Do someone know if we could take the arcs regular or where to find some information about it?

Comment: How do the linked questions not answer your question in detail?

Comment: @TedShifrin maybe it is not a wide used name but by regular curve I mean that if $\alpha :I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a curve and $I$ an interval, then $\alpha '(t) \neq 0 \forall t \in I$. I need the curve to be regular in order to use parametrization by arc length. In the posts they tell how to build a smooth curve, but nothing is said about it being regular. The use of the same word for different meanings depending on the branch is driving me a bit crazy

Comment: Ah, right, so you're working with actual parametrized curves, rather than just their images. I think the usual smoothing technique of convolving with an approximation of the identity will work fine, as it will give a smooth function that is $\epsilon$-close in the $C^1$ (in fact, even better) topology. Since the original function has derivative of norm $1$, except, say, at $t=t_0$,  the smoothed version will have derivative of norm at least $1-\epsilon$ everywhere.