# Do Riemannian manifolds have to be smooth to define a metric or can it be relaxed to differentiable, or even simply just a path-connected set?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If I have a path-connected (closed) differentiable manifold $M$ naturally in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example a path-connected component of the level set $h = 0$ with $h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ continuously differentiable such that $\mathrm{d}h$ is surjective on all $\mathbb{R}^n$, can I endow it with a metric? I am not looking for smooth properties, simply the notion of a distance.

I am guessing I can define the length of a continuous path as its length in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the distance between two points $x,y \in M$ as the infimum of the length of continuous paths on $M$ from $x$ to $y$. Would that make sense? (although differentiability here is not used)

Comment: As long as you have a locally Euclidean structure and a partition of unity, you should be able to define an inner product locally and then use the partition of unity to go global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general definition of the length of any continuous curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$, although it might be infinite. Namely, $\text{Length}(\gamma)$ is the *supremum*, over all partitions
$$0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_{K-1} < x_K = 1
$$
of the quantity
$$|\gamma(x_0)-\gamma(x_1)| \, + \, ... \, + \, |\gamma_{K-1} - \gamma_K|
$$
It's not too hard to prove that if $\gamma$ is a piecewise $C^1$ curve then $\text{Length}(\gamma) < \infty$; you can find that in many advanced calculus books.

If $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a connected $C^1$-differential manifold, it follows that it is path connected, and furthermore that any two points $x,y \in M$ are the endpoints of some piecewise $C^1$ path (one can actually get a $C^1$ path with a tiny bit more work, but it doesn't simplify anything else to do that).

One can now define $d(x,y)$, for any $x,y \in M$, to be the infimum of $\text{Length}(\gamma)$ taken over all $C^1$ paths $\gamma$ having endpoints $x,y$. And it's not too hard to prove that this is indeed a metric on $M$.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing, but limiting myself to continuous paths. That gives a notion of distance on any path-connected nonempty closed set, although one needs to check that between two points always exists a path of finite length. I would actually be interested if you had some more hints on that point, especially how one gets a piecewise-$\mathcal{C}^1$ path between any two points.

I guess I was more confusing than anything else by invoking a differential manifold.

Comment: It's not true that this gives a distance on any path-connected nonempty closed set.  The [Koch snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) is a popular counterexample.

Comment: Well, I am aware of this, but my set is a differentiable manifold. EDIT: So surely I would need this to prove the existence of _a_ finite length path (between any pair of points), but once it is done I can still write the infimum of length of continuous paths, not requiring them to be piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Comment: The point of a piecewise $C^1$ path is to find just one example of a path between $x$ and $y$ with finite length. Then yes, you simply take the infimum over all paths in $M$ with endpoints $x,y$. But without having that one example in your hands, it is possible that the infimum equals $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes thank you! Do you have a hint how to show that there always exists such a path (assuming $M$ is a nonempty path-connected closed differentiable manifold)?

Comment: You simply have to adapt the usual proof, found in a topology textbook such as Munkres, that a connected, locally path connected topological space is path connected. In the adaptation, one replaces "locally path connected" with "locally piecewise $C^1$ path connected" which is an obvious property of any $C^1$ manifold.

Comment: For reference, someone answered this question completely here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134129.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your definition of "manifold" (or "closed manifold"). If we use the standard terminology, it is correct to say that every paracompact differentiable manifold has a Riemannian metric (and Riemannian metric then defines a distance function on every connected component). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Existence_of_a_metric).

I think it does not make much sense to talk about the length of a continuous path if the path in question is not continuously differentiable. The reason is that there [exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Curves%20with%20infinite%20length) continuous paths that do not have finite length in the standard sense of the word (so some care should be applied when you define the infimum).

A less precise point: you ask if Riemannian manifolds have to be smooth to define a metric. There are so-called symplectic structures, to define which you need the manifold to be smooth. However, people also consider limits of diffeomorphisms preserving the symplectic structure that are not themselves differentiable (such continuous maps are named "symplectic homeomorphisms", see [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~vincent.humiliere/introC0SympTop.pdf)) and their dynamics is apparently pretty interesting. Possibly, one can do something similar with Riemannian structures but I am not sure (Riemannian structure is more rigid than the symplectic one so I doubt it but who knows).

Comment: I see, this is less pedestrian than I imagined! I think the definition by first length of path, then least length of path is the easiest to work with in my context. It is not a problem if the length of a path is infinite, what matters is actually that between any two points there exists a path of finite length.